# Python converted exe cannot find my .py scripts

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have `.py` file which is converted to `exe` however it can't find after `2table.py` and `3table.py` outputs the error `no such file or directory`.

**code:**

```
    from subprocess import call
    from tkinter import ttk
    import tkinter as Tk
    import tkinter.messagebox as mb



    root=Tk.Tk()
    root.title("Title")


    frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding     = 100)
    frm.grid()


    def table2():
        call(["python", '2table.py'])
        msg = "Success!"
        mb.showinfo("info", msg)
    def table3():
        call(["python", "3table.py"])
        msg = "Success!"
        mb.showinfo("info", msg)

    ttk.Button(frm, text="2 - table", command=table2).grid(column=2, row=0)
    ttk.Button(frm, text="3 - table ", command=table3).grid(column=2, row=2)

    ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).grid(column=4, row=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Buttons should run scripts.

I used `pyinstaller` to the additional `.py` files together with the main one, however, he still does not see them, and even if the files are in the folder where the converted `exe` still does not see them, it does not find mine at `startup.py` scripts and generally goes the other pathway

Comment: Why do you use `subprocess` to call the python script instead of imports?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your description what the problem is but you can try this.

```
from subprocess import call
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as Tk
import tkinter.messagebox as mb

root=Tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")

frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding = 100)
frm.grid()

workdir = os.getcwd() # Save current workdir
pathname_of_exe = sys.executable # Get the dir of the exe-file

def table2():
    os.chdir(pathname_of_exe) # Set workdir where the exe-file is located and 2table.py
    call(["python", '2table.py'])
    os.chdir(workdir) # Restore workdir to previously workdir
    msg = "Success!"
    mb.showinfo("info", msg)

def table3():
    os.chdir(pathname_of_exe) # Set workdir where the exe-file is located and 3table.py
    call(["python", "3table.py"])
    os.chdir(workdir) # Restore workdir to previously workdir
    msg = "Success!"
    mb.showinfo("info", msg)

ttk.Button(frm, text="2 - table", command=table2).grid(column=2, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="3 - table ", command=table3).grid(column=2, row=2)
```

It may not be necessary to restore the workdir, but in my example it is included. Beyond that consider whether it is necessary to use `subprocess` to call the python files.

Comment: hi, thank you for answering my problem, I solved it by changing the os from mac to Windows, but I now have another problem:After converting to exe the main.py opens 2/3table.py only after closing main.exe,maybe it is the use of subprocesses, but multiprocessing also did not help, I tried call the other py scripts using your code but it didn't run 2/3table.py while open main.exe,I have opened a new question and if you can answer it, could you answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75511577/have-problems-after-converting-to-exe-main-exe-cannot-call-py-scripts-while-it-i